# React Material UI DropDown Menu Doesn't Work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, materialize

I have a component to build a dynamic drop down menu based on a URL which is REST API:

Combo component code:

```
export default class Combo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {data: [], value: 0}
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Fetch content
  }
  handleChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <DropDownMenu style={styles.customWidth} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {this.state.data.map((row, i) => <ComboItem key={i} _id={row._id} label={row.name}/>)}
        </DropDownMenu>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export class ComboItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MenuItem style={styles.customWidth} value={this.props._id} key={this.props._id} primaryText={this.props.label}/>
    )
  }
}
```

in my `index.js` file I've added `injectTapEventPlugin`.

Finally it shows the output, but when I click on an item, it never change the value if drop down to the selected item (like normal selectbox).

Note: `onChange` method never called on any changes.

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need still need to pass `this.state.value` to the `DrowDownMenu` component as the `value` prop:

```
<DropDownMenu 
  style={styles.customWidth} 
  value={this.state.value} 
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
  {this.state.data.map((row, i) => <ComboItem key={i} _id={row._id} label={row.name}/>)}
</DropDownMenu>
```

**Edit:**

Because you are wrapping your `MenuItem` component you actually need to pass the `onTouchTap` function to the `MenuItem`s:

```
class ComboItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MenuItem 
        value={this.props._id} 
        key={this.props._id} 
        primaryText={this.props.label} 
        onTouchTap={this.props.onTouchTap}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This is usually done by the `Menu` component [here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Menu/Menu.js#L255).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added it, but still doesn't work. My `onChange` state never called when I select an item.

Comment: I think the other issue is that the children of the `DropDownMenu` component should be `MenuItem` components.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works with `onTouchTap` option.